# why does zookeeper-server-start from homebrew work with kafka server but not zkServer start

Tags: apache-kafka, homebrew, apache-zookeeper

both run using the same config file, but when I run `kafka-server-start` while `zkServer start` is running, I get this error `INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)`, but not when running `zookeeper-server-start`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **INFO** message, not an error.

Is something not working as expected? If so, the problem is elsewhere. Ignore it.

> but not when running zookeeper-server-start

Because Zookeeper isn't trying to connect to itself